# System.NullReferenceException when doing For...Each on Dictionary Array

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I may be incorrectly using the term "Dictionary Array", so please tell me the correct terminology if that is the case. In my code below, what I am referring to as a dictionary array is `Dim PdfIndividual(individualCount)`.

Essentially I am trying to get a lambda function to return a count after it iterates through my dictionary array and finds the value I am trying to get a count for.

I am limited in the framework where this code will eventually run which is why I am using a lambda function in the first place. So while I am sure the code I have presented may not be ideal, I am really just interested in understanding why the error occurs, versus just getting it to work.

```
Dim relationshipTypeCount As Func(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)(), String, Integer) =
    Function(PdfIndividualArray, relationshipType)
        Dim dictValue As String = ""
        Dim relTypeCountResult As Integer = 0
        For Each pdfIndDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) In PdfIndividualArray
            pdfIndDict.TryGetValue("RelationshipType", dictValue)
            If dictValue = relationshipType Then
                relTypeCountResult += 1
            End If
        Next
        Return relTypeCountResult
    End Function

Dim individualCount As Integer = 5
Dim relType As String = ""
Dim PdfIndividual(individualCount) As Dictionary(Of String, String)

For i As Integer = 0 To individualCount
    If i = 0 Then
         relType = "primary"
    ElseIf i <= 3 Then
         relType = "secondary"
    ElseIf i > 3 Then
         relType = "guest"
    End If
    PdfIndividual(i) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    PdfIndividual(i).Add("RelationshipType", relType)

    Dim relCount As Integer = relCount = relationshipTypeCount(PdfIndividual, relType)
Next
```

The error occurs on the dictionary element in the For...Each of my relationshipTypeCount lambda function.

The error text is:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
>
> pdfIndDict was Nothing.

Screenshot of the error exception
[image]

Comment: Debug your code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jmcilhinney. While I did so some debugging to get to the point where I posted my initial question, I realize I didn't step through it properly. Another look stepping through the lambda function and I think I see where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your targeted .NET version, you can use the following [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) form which is more concise:

```
For Each pdfIndDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) In PdfIndividualArray
    pdfIndDict?.TryGetValue("RelationshipType", dictValue)
    If dictValue = relationshipType Then relTypeCountResult += 1
Next pdfIndDict
```

BTW, you can also use the following null check form:

```
If pdfIndDict IsNot Nothing Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging further I realized that my issue was that I was iterating over an "array" that had 6 elements, however 5 of the elements were nothing at the time of the first call of the lambda function. So I just needed to add a check that the dictionary element I was handling was not nothing.

```
For Each pdfIndDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) In PdfIndividualArray
    If Not IsNothing(pdfIndDict) Then
        pdfIndDict.TryGetValue("RelationshipType", dictValue)
        If dictValue = relationshipType Then
            relTypeCountResult += 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```